# Visual C++ 2010 Express, Executable icon not replaced for all explorer views

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, icons, c++-cli

I have a simple C++/CLI Windows Forms application in Visual C++ 2010 Express. I decided to replace the EXE file icon there.

I deleted the original app.ico from the project, put another ico file (128*128 in case it matters) to the project directory.

Then I opened the app.rc file and replaced icon name there: from app.ico to Vocabulary2.ico (this is the ico file name)

Here is the code from app.rc file i've changed:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Icon
//
// Icon placed first or with lowest ID value becomes application icon
LANGUAGE 25, 1
1           ICON         "Vocabulary2.ico"  //changed the value in quotes
```

Then I cleaned and rebuilt the solution and I have the following problem with app's icon: correct icon is shown when windows explorer is in Content\Details\List\Small Icons mode. But if I switch to any other mode (Medium, (Extra) Large Icons, Tiles) - I see the default application icon.

This is not some windows explorer cache - I have copied the file on another computer with Windows 7 and got the same problem.

How can I set the right icon for all views?

Here is the link to the icon I used: http://findicons.com/icon/download/94320/applications_office/128/ico?id=275134

Here is the screenshot of the problem:
[image: screenshot - different icons for tiles and content view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Windows ICO file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_%28file_format%29) can contain multiple icons of different sizes and color formats. That feature is something you need to take advantage of here. Windows uses these different icons in various places in the user interface, depending on the size that is required and the color format supported by the machine. If an exact match is not found, it tries to scale one of the existing icons to fit, but this often produces ugly results (or may not be attempted at all, as in your case).

Right now, you only have a single icon in your ICO file: a 128x128 pixel icon that uses 32-bit colors. That's not enough to satisfy all the basic required sizes. In fact, I don't think Windows even uses 128 pixel icons anywhere. The basic sizes that you need are 16, 32, 48, and 256 pixels. You can optionally include a 24x24 pixel icon, which I believe is used for the "Content" view and in certain Start menu layouts. So, in summary:

- 16x16 pixels (e.g. "Small Icons" and "Details" views)
- *[optional]* 24x24 pixels (e.g. "Content" view)
- 32x32 pixels (e.g. "Medium Icons" view)
- 48x48 pixels (e.g. "Tiles" view)
- 256x256 pixels (e.g. "Extra Large Icons" view)

If you want to support older machines that might not support 32-bit color icons, you also need to include icons in all of the above sizes in lower color formats. You could include *all* of the color formats, but I find it's sufficient to just have a set of 32-bit and 8-bit color icons in all the required sizes.

You will need a good icon creator to handle this for you, as Microsoft Paint doesn't support creating ICO files that contain multiple icons. I used to recommend [IcoFX](http://icofx.ro/), but it's no longer free. You can download an older version (1.6.4) various places online, but I'll let you Google for that yourself. If you already have one or the other, Photoshop and the GIMP both support creating ICO files. There are plenty of other choices online; for example [this one](http://www.free-icon-editor.com/) (although I haven't tried it).

Full versions of Visual Studio do come with an icon editor, but I wouldn't use it. It still doesn't (at least as of VS 2010) properly support 32-bit color icons. The alpha channels get all screwed up.

You can either have your icon editor scale your icons up/down to create all the required sizes, or you can use it to hand-draw the other sizes. Hand drawing (or at least hand manipulation) often produces better results. Scaling a large icon down often makes it unrecognizable. Scaling a smaller icon up often produces jaggies and other ugly visual artifacts.

Since you're using an icon drawn by someone else, you can just download the other sizes from [the original link](http://findicons.com/icon/94320/applications_office?id=275134#) (click the "Other Sizes" tab). I believe the way the FindIcons site is designed, you have to download each size individually as a separate ICO file, and then use your icon editor to copy and paste each of those into a new ICO file.

Further reading:

- [Icons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511280.aspx), from the Windows Aero UI Guidelines
- [Creating Windows XP Icons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997636.aspx) (an older article that may not be entirely relevant anymore, but still contains some great information)